# Does comparator interface inherit Object class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I think it might, because the Comparator interface contains an `equals` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below link

> http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Comparator.java.html

You can see in the code that Comparator interface has its own equals method.

Comment: @Abhisek , Ya this looks like Comparator Interface having its own method.

Comment: ... but you could call equals *regardless* of it being declared in Comparator.

Comment: @akai: If this answers the question, than the question was worded really badly. It only repeats what you already wrote in the question.

Comment: This is just about clicking arbitrary Stack Overflow buttons for fun :)

Answer (score 8):

From [section 9.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.2):

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface. It is a compile-time error if the interface explicitly declares such a method m in the case where m is declared to be final in Object.

This allows you to call any of the `Object` methods via a reference of an interface type - which makes sense, given that the *implementation* will certainly be a subclass of `Object`.

EDIT: In the case of `Comparator`, it so happens that `equals` is *explicitly* redeclared, in order to provide more documentation. However, you'd be able to call `equals` on a `Comparator` reference anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No interface implements Object class but the implementation does

Answer (score 1):

No interfaces **ever** extends/inherit an `Object`. Only it's implemented classes does extends `Object` implicitly (if not explicitly extended).

The `Comparator.equals()` method follows the same signature as `Object.equals()` method. The reason for this is stated on the JavaDoc:

> However, overriding this method may,
>   in some cases, improve performance by
>   allowing programs to determine that
>   two distinct comparators impose the
>   same order.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, every class will ultimately extend `Object`. While you can't instanciate `Comparator` itself, all comparator implementations will still extend `Object`.

The `equals()` method is redeclared in `Comparator` in order to adapt the Javadoc for the special contract that `Comparator` imposes on `equals()`

Answer (score 1):

Interface types are not officially subtypes of Object, but behave as if they were:

- They also implicitly declare all the methods of Object (as quoted by Jon)
- They can be converted to Object by an widening conversion without an explicit cast
- All objects of the interface type are automatically objects of the object type

In this case, the interface type redeclares the equals method in a compatible way, and the implementation from Object is used if the implementing class does not provide its own implementation.

The specification here is done in a way that the default implementation from Object.equals also fits the specification of Comparator.equals, and that every (conformant) implementation of Comparator.equals also fits the specification of Object.equals.

Answer (score 0):

In java, an interface can never be created by inheriting it from a class. So, no, `Comparator` interface doesn't inherit `Object` class.

Comment: Seems like my twin brother :)

Answer (score 0):

The **interfaces are like Roles** and **its responsibilities are declared as interface methods**.

Comparator being the interface just lists all the responsibilities which needs to be provided by a class which implements this interface.

The object of the class which implements Comparator will be subclass of the Object class.